# R - handing duplicate rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a Dataframe which looks like below:

```
Head1 Head2
10  46
10  52
10  46
20  53
20  53
30  12
30  12
30  52
```

I need the output to be like this :

```
Head1 Head2
10  46
10  52
10  #
20  53
20  #
30  12
30  #
30  52
```

I tried `unique(Head2)` which returns only the unique values of `Head2`.

Example 2:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: I want to replace all the duplicates in each group by "#", but leaving behind the first entry alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Head1', and specify the 'i' (`duplicated(Head2)`), assign (`:=`) the duplicated elements in 'Head2' to 'NA'.  If we change it to `#`, it could result in changing the class of the `numeric` column to `character`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[duplicated(Head2), Head2 := NA_integer_ , by = Head1]
df1
#    Head1 Head2
#1:    10    46
#2:    10    52
#3:    10    NA
#4:    20    53
#5:    20    NA
#6:    30    12
#7:    30    NA
#8:    30    13
```

Based on the updated example and expected output

```
setDT(df1)[df1[,duplicated(.SD)], Head2 := NA_integer_]
df1
#    Head1 Head2
#1:    10    46
#2:    10    52
#3:    10    NA
#4:    20    53
#5:    20    NA
#6:    30    12
#7:    30    NA
#8:    30    52
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset,

```
setDT(df2)[df2[ , duplicated(.SD)], Head2 := "#"]
df2
#   Head1         Head2
#1:    10 solution fhdd
#2:    10      solution
#3:    11      solution
#4:    11            NA
#5:    11      thid djd
#6:    11             #
#7:    11             #
#8:    11             #
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(Head1 = c(10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L
 ), Head2 = c("solution fhdd", "solution", "solution", NA, "thid djd", 
 NA, "solution", "thid djd")), .Names = c("Head1", "Head2"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: The answer you provided replaces duplicate values in Head2 with NA irrespective of considering Head1 entries. But what I need is , the duplicate Head2 values should be replaced with NA only for identical Head1 values. I have modified my input and output dataset.. Please refer to my question once again

Comment: @Rambo Updated the post

Comment: @akrun...The output I expect is something different. Please understand my context that the duplicates should be replaced with "#" taking into account the Head1 values too... E.g. For Head1 value "10", I have 3 Head2 values for it (46,52,46)... The code should check for duplicates only inside the subset (46,52,46) and replace them with "#". I do not want to scan the whole of Head2 values for the presence of each and every duplicate

Comment: @Rambo As I mentioned in the post, changing to `#` will altogether change the class of the column, which is not very useful.  Instead, you should change it to NA.  Regarding the duplicate, I am getting your expected output.

Comment: I need "#" only replaced. I dont mind if the class of the column is changed

Comment: Please take into account that Head1 and Head2 are of type character and not numeric i.e any character can be present in the values

Comment: @Rambo If they are of 'character', then use `Head2 := "#"]` instead of `Head2 := NA_integer_]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127151/discussion-between-rambo-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df[which(duplicated(df)),]$Head2 <- '#'
df
    Head1 Head2
1    10    46
2    10    52
3    10     #
4    20    53
5    20     #
6    30    12
7    30     #
8    30    13
```

With the modified table

```
> df
10  46
10  52
10  46
20  53
20  53
30  12
30  12
30  52
```

with the same code we can get the desired output:

```
  Head1 Head2
1    10    46
2    10    52
3    10     #
4    20    53
5    20     #
6    30    12
7    30     #
8    30    52
```

Again with the new df,

```
df <- read.table(text='Head1 Head2
                 10  solution_fhdd
                 10  soulution
                 11  solution
                 11  NA
                 11  thid_djd
                 11  NA
                 11  solution
                 11  thid_djd', header=TRUE)

df$Head2 <- as.character(df$Head2) # convert factor to character (if class(Head2)=='factor')
df[which(duplicated(df)),]$Head2 <- '#'
df

  Head1         Head2
1    10 solution_fhdd
2    10     soulution
3    11      solution
4    11          <NA>
5    11      thid_djd
6    11             #
7    11             #
8    11             #
```

Comment: @sandipan...The output I expect is something different. Please understand my context that the duplicates should be replaced with "#" taking into account the Head1 values too... E.g. For Head1 value "10", I have 3 Head2 values for it (46,52,46)... The code should check for duplicates only inside the subset (46,52,46) and replace them with "#". I do not want to scan the whole of Head2 values for the presence of each and every duplicate. Please refer my updated question above and the values need not essentially be numbers alone..They can be characters too

Comment: @Rambo did not quite get you, right now the code is taking both the columns Head1, Head2 into account to find duplicates and also with the modified table in your post we can get the desired output with the same code. Are you talking about efficiency?

Comment: @Rambo with your new requirement, we just need to add one additional line to the start to convert factor to character if class(Head2) is factor. If the class(Head2) is character then the same code works (updated the answer with the actual output which is the desired one i guess).

Answer (score 1):

Using base-R:

```
df$Head2 <- unlist(by(df[,-1], df[,1], FUN=function(x) replace(x,duplicated(x),NA)))
##  Head1 Head2
##1    10    46
##2    10    52
##3    10    NA
##4    20    53
##5    20    NA
##6    30    12
##7    30    NA
##8    30    13
```

The `by` command groups the data in its first argument by he factor in its second argument and applies a function to each group. Here, the first argument is all columns of the input data frame `df` except the first, which is `df$Head2`, and we group these by the values in the first column of `df`, which is `df$Head1`. The function that is applied `replace`es `duplicated` values of its input with `NA`. The function `by` returns a list whose elements are the outputs of the function by each group. We `unlist` these to a vector and then set `df$Head2` to this result.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Head1 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L
), Head2 = c(46L, 52L, 46L, 53L, 53L, 12L, 12L, 13L)), .Names = c("Head1", 
"Head2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
##  Head1 Head2
##1    10    46
##2    10    52
##3    10    46
##4    20    53
##5    20    53
##6    30    12
##7    30    12
##8    30    13
```

---

If both columns of `df` are `characters`, and the OP wishes to replace duplicates in `df$Head2` within groups of `df$Head1`, then:

```
df$Head2 <- unlist(by(df[,-1], df[,1], FUN=function(x) replace(as.character(x),duplicated(x),'#')))
##  Head1 Head2
##1    10    46
##2    10    52
##3    10     #
##4    20    53
##5    20     #
##6    30    12
##7    30     #
##8    30    13
```

Here, the data is from your original post (but with columns that are characters):

```
df <- structure(list(Head1 = c("10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "30", 
"30", "30"), Head2 = c("46", "52", "46", "53", "53", "12", "12", 
"13")), .Names = c("Head1", "Head2"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
##  Head1 Head2
##1    10    46
##2    10    52
##3    10    46
##4    20    53
##5    20    53
##6    30    12
##8    30    13
```

With your new data:

```
df <- structure(list(Head1 = c("10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11"), Head2 = c("solution fhdd", "solution", "solution", 
NA, "thid djd", NA, "solution", "thid djd")), .Names = c("Head1", 
"Head2"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
##  Head1         Head2
##1    10 solution fhdd
##2    10      solution
##3    11      solution
##4    11          <NA>
##5    11      thid djd
##6    11          <NA>
##7    11      solution
##8    11      thid djd
```

We get:

```
df$Head2 <- unlist(by(df[,-1], df[,1], FUN=function(x) replace(as.character(x),duplicated(x),'#')))
##  Head1         Head2
##1    10 solution fhdd
##2    10      solution
##3    11      solution
##4    11          <NA>
##5    11      thid djd
##6    11             #
##7    11             #
##8    11             #
```

Comment: @aichao...The output I expect is something different. Please understand my context that the duplicates should be replaced with "#" taking into account the Head1 values too... E.g. For Head1 value "10", I have 3 Head2 values for it (46,52,46)... The code should check for duplicates only inside the subset (46,52,46) and replace them with "#". I do not want to scan the whole of Head2 values for the presence of each and every duplicate. Please refer my updated question above and the values need not essentially be numbers alone..They can be characters too